# Where to start with text classification from a two column (label, text) data source?

Tags: python, machine-learning

We receive abuse complaints from third parties.  I've exported a whole whack of the complaints in XML format and then compiled them into a pandas DataFrame() while scrubbing things like email addresses, hostnames, URLs, and IP addresses out like the following.

The file 'learning_data.txt' consists of thousands of lines each looking like this:

```
<label>:<a long string of text>
```

**Script so far**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd


def main():
    data = open('learning_data.txt').readlines()

    print('Loading data...')
    labels, texts = ([], [])
    for line in data:
        label, text = line.split(':', 1)
        labels.append(label)
        texts.append(text)

    print('Adding to pandas DataFrame()')
    trainDF = pd.DataFrame()
    trainDF['label'] = labels
    trainDF['text'] = texts

    print(trainDF)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
                                                   label                                               text
8            Attacks and Reconnaissance__SSH Brute Force   Abuse from ... Dear Administrator,  We have d...
9                        Malicious Code/Traffic__Unknown    - [ Vulnerable Host in Canada] In support of...
10               Fraud__Copyright/Trademark Infringement   Unauthorized Use of Copyrights RE: TC--b--- *...
...                                                  ...                                                ...
43635                    Malicious Code/Traffic__Unknown   tdss report about ... last detected -- :: Sec...
43636                                    Fraud__Phishing   Issue : phishing attack at /// Dear Sir or Ma...
```

The label format is __ because I don't expect to do multiple classifications yet, if ever.

All of the demos I've seen for machine learning and text classification use some black-box data source like the 20 newsgroups etc.  Since I'm starting with my own data I'm having trouble figuring it into the examples/tutorials.

Edit: I'm using Python 3.6.6

Where do I go from here?

Should I be using sklearn or some other library?  Pytorch?  How do I make features out of the text and add those to a label?  How do I write the learned data out so I can then use another script to use that dataset to predict the labels for new text?

I'm starting from scratch here with machine learning but I've done tons of stuff in Python unrelated to machine learning.

Comment: This should be helpful:  https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-nlp-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-python-and-nltk-c52b92a7c73a

Comment: are the observations in your dataset labeled for example ===> abuse/ non-abuse

Comment: You can use SKLearn CountVectorizer or TF/IDF to create features from the text data. You can then easily use RandomForest which is a good classifier for training such problems.

Comment: @Inder I've been to that link before but it's one of the ones that uses the pre-made dataset "fetch_20newsgroups".

Comment: @EkabaBisong All of the texts associated with each label are definitely abuse reports.  I'm not 100% sure what you mean though.

Comment: @EkabaBisong I tried getting started with TfidfVectorizer but after instantiating the class I'm not clear on what to do with it in order to get this two column DataFrame from pandas loaded into it.

Comment: @TheZeke To build a machine learning classifier, we need to have examples of text that is also non-abusive, so the model can learn to distinguish between the classes `abuse` and `non-abuse` when given a text input.

Comment: this has example that prepares dataset :: https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-text-data-machine-learning-scikit-learn/

Comment: @TheZeke See my answer to help with getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SKLearn `CountVectorizer` or `TF-IDF`. Here's a rough outlay for an approach:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier  
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

count_vect = CountVectorizer()

text = ['text1', ..] 

targets = ['abuse', ...]

matrix = count_vect.fit_transform(text)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
targets = encoder.fit_transform(targets)

randomForest = RandomForestClassifier()

randomForest.fit(matrix, targets)
```

Comment: I've updated my post with some code describing how I get the DataFrame.  The script that built the text file is much more complicated but it's moot.  From your example the text list would be `texts` from my script.  And targets would be `labels` from my script.  Correct?

Comment: Seen. In any case, my answer still provides a helpful template for this project. You have to do some data cleaning and labeling to get your data into a DataFrame in the form of [text, labels => (abuse, non-abuse)]

Comment: OK I've implemented what you wrote up (thank you!).  It executes without issue.  I'm not clear on why I need negative texts as well (texts that are not abuse related).  I'm attempting to label texts with a classification of what kind of abuse they are but not if they are abuse related or not.  If the text has phishing related or malware related they should be labeled differently. Examples would be ['Malicious Code/Traffic__Aaeh', 'Malicious Code/Traffic__Phishing', 'Vulnerabilities__Software Version', ...]

Comment: Okay. That's fine. You are on the right track. All I was emphasizing was that the text examples should have **some sort of labels** for the classifier to learn to distinguish the classes. Don't forget to accept and upvote :)